Address Settings crash on Wordpress
After a fresh install of CiviCRM 5.72.3 on WordPress localized in Italian, CiviCRM crash simply choosing
Administer -> Localization -> Address Settings
Note that I already set geocoding using Google and providing the API Key.
Any idea?
